# How to do CORS request with react-app and webpack - no expressjs

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to make a GET request to another website (not API) by axios but it's blocked by CORS policy.
I also attempted to set up webpack dev server with headers, but the result keeps unchanged

```
headers: {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
},
```

Comment: Welcome, this is your first post and let me congratulate you it is already better than most. As is the fashion you started your question with a problem, followed by a brief explanation of things you already tried. May I suggest you elaborate on that and conclude with a statement of your expectation. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that that you'll have to rewrite the CORS-headers coming from that other website *before* it hits your browser. One way to do this is by using [webpack devserver](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) to proxy that other website and then [rewriting the response headers](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-events)

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/path/you/want/to/proxy': 
            target: 'https://another.website.com',
                onProxyRes(proxyRes, req, res) {
                    proxyRes.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
                    proxyRes.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS';
                    proxyRes.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization';
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: this way only works with a specific destination. I'm trying to make something more flexible than

Comment: You could always specify `'*'` as the path you want to proxy? That would intercept everything